# Why am I getting a pre-flight error with CORS setup on Express?

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, cors, preflight

I am setting up a rest api for a personal site. My personal site is built with Vue.js and the api server is built with express. I have tried a couple different CORS configurations on the server but I seem to still get the pre-flight error so I assume I am lacking understanding somewhere.

The original goal was for me to learn about docker by containerizing the api/auth server and hosting it separately from the frontend vue.js app. Is this a part of the problem or bad practice?

Below are the two CORS configs I tried which I found on other posts but have had no success with.

Config #1:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {

    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://0.0.0.0:5000"); // I tried setting a specific IP as well as the * wildcard
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-type,Accept,X-Custom-Header");

    // I think this if statement should respond the preflight request.
    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
        return res.status(200).end();
    }

    return next()

})
```

Config #2:

```
const whitelist = [
    'http://0.0.0.0:5000',
];
const corsOptions = {
    origin: function(origin, callback){
        var originIsWhitelisted = whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1;
        callback(null, originIsWhitelisted);
    },
    credentials: true
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

I am also wondering if it has something to do with how I'm making the request so I've added the method that is being used from the Vue.js app:

```
attemptLogin: function(event) {
            event.preventDefault()
            axios.post('http://0.0.0.0:5000/auth/login', { 
                username: this.username, 
                password: this.password 
            })
            .then(res => {
                if (res.data.success) {
                    this.updateLoginStatus()
                    this.updateJwt(res.data.token)
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            });
        }
```

Other potentially useful information:

I tried running both the frontend and the backend on the same computer with no luck. Now I am running the backend on my laptop and the frontend on my desktop.

Here are the GitHub Repos for both repositories if you need more context:

Frontend: https://github.com/lwerner27/personal-vue

Backend: https://github.com/lwerner27/personal-backend

Comment: What’s the exact error messages the browser is logging in the devtools console? What’s the HTTP status code of the responses?

Comment: Here is a link to a screenshot of the console https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ywS0L0wMSozHO2GoufLvvFmNr2vd-NOf

Comment: What status code and headers do you get back when you use curl or Postman or something to send an OPTIONS request to `http://10.10.81.100:5000/auth/login`? e.g., using curl, `curl -i -X OPTIONS -H "Origin: http://localhost:8080" http://10.10.81.100:5000/auth/login`

Comment: Here is what I got in postman: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BFUe2tyC2Ub35vZ1nI3p4gfu-fHIRZlp

Comment: Postman doesn't need to do a pre-flight, so it won't fail. Browsers alone to pre-flight options requests.

Comment: Thank you for your help @sideshowbarker, I got it working by going down to the simplest form of a CORS implementation: app.use(cors()). Which I swear I tried. If you can think of any reason why those other configs wouldn't be sending the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header I'd be interested to hear your thoughts.

Comment: Your vue site.url is localhost:8080. In config 1 try putting http://localhost:8080 in res.header function

Answer (score 0):

If you are running from same origin, it shouldn't be a problem. I suspect that you are running Vue app through npm run serve, then pointing it at the back end server, which is running in a different server.

Try creating directory in your backend called public. In Vue, run `npm run build` and then take the minified files and place them in the public directory.

Then give access to it in node, using express:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Comment: I understand this method would work. My goal is to have my API on a server that is independent of the vue.js app though.

Comment: I can't think of a reason to do this. It looks like you are whitelisting your server (port 5000) instead of your localhost:8080. Plus you can't whitelist local host, so you'll need to deploy both of these to a cloud provide OR whitelist your local ip. You are fighting a battle you don't need to fight.

Comment: Here's the reference to inability to whitelist localhost:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/deadly-cors-when-http-localhost-is-the-origin

Answer (score 0):

the problem might be that instead of

```
axios.post('http://0.0.0.0:5000/auth/login', { 
                username: this.username, 
                password: this.password 
            })
```

try `using http://0.0.0.0:5000/auth/login/`
I used to have preflight error also on mozilla and other browsers if it's not slashed at the end. May i know what's the exact CORS error you are having?